# MVC 4 Clicking a Button to get a Partial Page

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a page with a search property. The user will enter a number in the search field and hit the submit button. I need to be able to call a controller method in order to run the search code.

For now I am just trying to hit a partial page to just get some functionality in there. Below is the code I have so far. As of now nothing happens when I click the button. I hear Ajax was something to use so I have been playing with that a little. I am still learning the framework so bear with me.

```
<div class="span6 roundedCorners">
    <div class="row-fluid Title">
        <div class="span6">
            Search Area
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid individual">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4"><span class="pull-right fieldDescription">Number</span></div>
            <div class="span8"><input /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12" id="adminSubmitButton">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "_adminDetails" }))
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse">Submit</button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In your code there is no element to update (with ID - _adminDetails)

Comment: Ahh, yeah thats the my partial view. That feels incorrect now that i am looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is empty, it only has a submit button. You will need to move your search button inside the form. Something like this:

Model

```
public class SearchModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Query { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model SearchModel

...
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "_adminDetails" }))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Query)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Query)
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse">Submit</button>
}

<div id="_adminDetails"></di>
```

**Note:** Make sure you have an element with id `_adminDetails`

Your controller will have to take the model and perform the search. Example:

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(SearchModel model)
 {
    //do something with your model (perform search)
    return View(results);
 }
```

Comment: hmmmm ... well I dont have a "SearchModel" at the top of the view, as of now. What i am thinking should happen is, the user puts in a number in the field. when the user clicks submit a controller method would be called with the number as a parameter. My code then returns a List<SomeObject> to a partial view and are then displayed under my search block. I'm just not sure how to code it to do it.

Comment: SearchModel was just an example on how to do it with a model. The concept is the same though, you can just omit it and put a input element with name `query`. Then, your controller method will take a parameter withe the same name (`query`).

Comment: after doing some more reading I ended up going in your direction. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have it partially working now. When i click the button I am able to call the controller method using:

```
function adminButton()
        {
            $("#adminDetails").load("@Url.Action("ControllerMethod", "ControllerName")");
        }
```

The @Url.Action helper allows me to call the method which returns a partial view. This is a step in the right direction. But from what I am reading I should be able to use the following Url helper instead of the @Url.Action:

```
"@Url("ControllerMethod", "ControllerName")/" + submitButton.Value
```

I have tried some variations and I am still doing some reading to figure out a solution. Is there a helper that would let me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I did end up getting my problem solved friday evening. Basically what I did was load the partial page when the button was clicked through the help of JS/jQuery and the Razor @Url.Action() to call the controller method that returns a PartialView:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function adminButton()
    {
        var link = "@Url.Action("ControllerMethod", "ControllerClass", new { 
                                         number = -1})";

        var num = parseInt($("#number").val());

        link = link.replace(-1, num);

        $("#details").load(link);
    }
</script>
```